# Unable to connect to the router using ncclient on RedHat 9.0 on IBM PowerPC

Tags: cisco, netconf

I have a simple program using netconf client version `ncclient 0.6.13` with Python3 running on PPC64LE Red hat Version `Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.2 (Plow)`
which is using netconf yang to connect to the remote Cisco router.

```
import os
from ncclient import manager

# Define the device connection details


# Define the NETCONF filter for DHCP pool configuration
filter = """
<filter xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native">
    <hostname></hostname>
  </native>
</filter>
"""


# Establish a NETCONF session with the device
with manager.connect(host="192.168.20.55", port=830, username="test user", password="password", hostkey_verify=False, allow_agent=False,  look_for_keys=False, device_params={'name':'csr'}) as m:
    response = m.get_config("running", filter)
    # Print the XML response
    print(response.xml)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                             
      File "/usr/lib/powerns-vpn/alpha.py", line 26, in <module>         
        with manager.connect(host="192.168.2.57", port=830, username="admin", password="Pwr4cld!", hostkey_verify=False, allow_agent=False,  look_for_keys=False, device_params={'name':'csr'}) as m:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ncclient/manager.py", line 176, in connect
        return connect_ssh(*args, **kwds)                                 
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ncclient/manager.py", line 143, in connect_ssh
        session.connect(*args, **kwds)                                    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ncclient/transport/ssh.py", line 331, in connect
        self._transport.start_client()                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 660, in start_client
        raise e                                                                   
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2075, in run
        self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)       
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py", line 53, in parse_next
        return self._parse_kexecdh_reply(m)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py", line 136, in _parse_kexecdh_reply
        self.transport._verify_key(K_S, sig)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1886, in _verify_key
        if not key.verify_ssh_sig(self.H, Message(sig)):                               
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 133, in verify_ssh_sig
        key.verify(                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 582, in verify
        _rsa_sig_verify(
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 308, in _rsa_sig_verify
        pkey_ctx = _rsa_sig_setup(
      File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 236, in _rsa_sig_setup
        raise UnsupportedAlgorithm(
    cryptography.exceptions.UnsupportedAlgorithm: sha1 is not supported by this backend for RSA signing.
```

Comment: As it says, it does not support SHA1. You need to use newer than that.

Comment: Is this key coming from the Router Side...
If this key is generated at the client side, what params I have to use for it so it is not SHA1.

Comment: As I understand, this key coming from the Router Side.
Is there a way on how to set this so the IOS-XE router does not send SHA1 Key.

Comment: That would depend on what router hardware you have and which firmware version it is using. You might find help here, if your version of IOS-Xe is similar: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst9500/software/release/17-3/configuration_guide/sec/b_173_sec_9500_cg/ssh_algorithms_for_common_criteria_certification.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch. @FrameHowitzer. This is the version I have on my Router. Strange thing is that it does work on Redhat 8.6 (PPC64LE) and RedHat 9.1( X86_64).
By the way this is the version I am having
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 17.03.04a

Comment: That makes sense. As newer Linux (and other operating systems) versions are released, they require higher/newer security integrations and features. Linux in recent versions has updated OpenSSH software which is configured by default to required key exchange that is better than SHA1. The link I shared before will show how to configure SHA2 key and MAC algorithm settings for the router so it will initiate and negotiate SSH connections with a higher level of security and should make Linux happy.